# node.js - Creating instance of a class directly from require

Tags: node.js, oop, constructor, instance, require

I have a class in a seperate file. I need to create an instance of it in another file. I tried this:

```
var connection = new require('./connection.js')("ef66143e996d");
```

But this is not working as I wanted. Right now I am using this as a temporary solution:

```
var Connection = require('./connection.js'); 
connection = new Connection("ef66143e996d");
```

Two Questions;

First, why doesn't that work.
Second, how can I accomplish this with a one-liner?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `new` keyword applies itself on the first function it comes across. In this case, that happens to be `require`. Wrapping the statement in parentheses will expose the correct function:

```
var connection = new (require('./connection.js'))("ef66143e996d");
```

Comment: This works, ok. But I invoked the `require` with `("ef66143e996d")`. Why doesn't `new` apply to the function returned from `require('./connection.js')("ef66143e996d")`. This must be the first function it comes across.

Comment: When running `new require('connection')()`, require is the first function it comes across. It's being evaluated left-to-right. Wrapping `require('connection')` in parentheses makes it so that whatever the parentheses resolves to is what `new` is being applied to.

Comment: To clarify, assuming `require('./connection.js')` exposes the function `Connection`, the `Connection` function _isn't_ exposed until the `require` function is invoked. The `new` keyword would trigger before the `require` function _unless_ the function is wrapped in parentheses. It is the same reason `3 * 2 + 1 = 7`, but `3 * (2 + 1) = 9`. Think of the `new` keyword as the multiplication in this example--it has a higher precedence.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation, you made things clearer in mind.